# jScrollPane sticking scrollbar problem with Drupal

Tags: drupal, jscrollpane

I have a Drupal site using jScrollPane that has a problem with the scrollbar dragger. When you single click on the scrollbar dragger it will not release the cursor's hold on the dragger until you double-click elsewhere on the page. An example can be seen here: http://webdev2.msi.ucsb.edu/lunch . Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already got your answer elsewhere, mollybt, but for the record, this issue appears to arise from the fact that the jScrollPane plugin requires jQuery 1.4+, whereas Drupal 6 ships with jQuery 1.2.6. Apparently [some folks](http://groups.google.com/group/jscrollpane/browse_thread/thread/694dbfa054bc27b2?pli=1) have had success patching the library for backward compatibility, but the easier solutions are to **1)** downgrade to jScrollPane 1.x or **2)** upgrade jQuery to 1.4+ (using the [jQuery Update module](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) for Drupal, for example).

Comment: Thanks a lot TravisCarden, I am pretty sure I ended up downgrading jScrollpane.